# Why is RTM_DELETE request on routing socket failing on macos

Tags: macos, sockets, routes

I'm trying to delete a route using a routing socket on MacOS.

I send an RTM_GET request and receive the expected address and netmask.
I pass these to an RTM_DELETE request, and the 'write' command returns ESRCH - I understand this means the route is not found in the table.

Running 'route delete' from the command line with the same arguments **does** succeed.
What am I missing?

This is the code I'm testing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <net/route.h>
#include <net/if_dl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

void deleteRoute(const char* destination, const char* netmask) {
  int sockfd = socket(AF_ROUTE, SOCK_RAW, 0);
  if (sockfd < 0) {
    std::cerr << "Error opening routing socket." << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  struct rt_msghdr* rtmsg;
  char buf[2048];

  rtmsg = reinterpret_cast<struct rt_msghdr*>(buf);
  std::memset(rtmsg, 0, sizeof(struct rt_msghdr));

  rtmsg->rtm_msglen = sizeof(struct rt_msghdr) + sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) * 2;
  rtmsg->rtm_version = RTM_VERSION;
  rtmsg->rtm_type = RTM_DELETE;
  rtmsg->rtm_flags = RTF_UP | RTF_GATEWAY;
  rtmsg->rtm_addrs = RTA_DST | RTA_NETMASK;
  rtmsg->rtm_pid = getpid();

  // Destination address
  struct sockaddr_in* dst_sa = reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr_in*>(buf + sizeof(struct rt_msghdr));
  dst_sa->sin_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  dst_sa->sin_family = AF_INET;
  inet_pton(AF_INET, destination, &(dst_sa->sin_addr));

  // Netmask
  struct sockaddr_in* netmask_sa = reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr_in*>(buf + sizeof(struct rt_msghdr) + sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
  netmask_sa->sin_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  netmask_sa->sin_family = AF_INET;
  inet_pton(AF_INET, netmask, &(netmask_sa->sin_addr));

  // Send the RTM_DELETE request
  ssize_t result = write(sockfd, buf, rtmsg->rtm_msglen);
  if (result < 0) {
    std::cerr << "Error writing delete to routing socket. Error code: " << errno << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Route deletion successful." << std::endl;
  }

  close(sockfd);
}

void processRouteReply(const char* destination, char* replyBuf, ssize_t replySize) {
  (void)destination;
  (void)replySize;
  struct rt_msghdr* rtmsg = reinterpret_cast<struct rt_msghdr*>(replyBuf);

  // Check if the reply message is of the expected type
  if (rtmsg->rtm_type == RTM_GET) {
    // Extract destination and netmask information
    struct sockaddr_in* dst_sa = reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr_in*>(replyBuf + sizeof(struct rt_msghdr));
    struct sockaddr_in* netmask_sa = reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr_in*>(replyBuf + sizeof(struct rt_msghdr) + 2 * sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    // Convert sockaddr_in structures to string representations
    char dst_str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    char netmask_str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(dst_sa->sin_addr), dst_str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(netmask_sa->sin_addr), netmask_str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

    std::cout << "Extracted Information from RTM_GET Reply:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Destination: " << dst_str << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Netmask: " << netmask_str << std::endl;

    // Use extracted information to delete the route
    deleteRoute(dst_str, netmask_str);
  } else {
    std::cerr << "Unexpected RTM_GET reply type: " << rtmsg->rtm_type << std::endl;
  }
}

void getRouteInfo(const char* destination, char* replyBuf, ssize_t replySize) {
  int sockfd = socket(AF_ROUTE, SOCK_RAW, 0);
  if (sockfd < 0) {
    std::cerr << "Error opening routing socket." << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  struct rt_msghdr* rtmsg;
  char buf[2048];

  rtmsg = reinterpret_cast<struct rt_msghdr*>(buf);
  std::memset(rtmsg, 0, sizeof(struct rt_msghdr));

  rtmsg->rtm_msglen = sizeof(struct rt_msghdr) + sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  rtmsg->rtm_version = RTM_VERSION;
  rtmsg->rtm_type = RTM_GET;
  rtmsg->rtm_flags = RTF_UP | RTF_GATEWAY;
  rtmsg->rtm_addrs = RTA_DST;
  rtmsg->rtm_pid = getpid();

  // Destination address
  struct sockaddr_in* dst_sa = reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr_in*>(buf + sizeof(struct rt_msghdr));
  dst_sa->sin_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  dst_sa->sin_family = AF_INET;
  inet_pton(AF_INET, destination, &(dst_sa->sin_addr));

  // Send the RTM_GET request
  ssize_t result = write(sockfd, buf, rtmsg->rtm_msglen);
  if (result < 0) {
    std::cerr << "Error writing GET to routing socket. Error code: " << errno << std::endl;
    close(sockfd);
    return;
  }

  // Receive and process the RTM_GET reply
  result = read(sockfd, replyBuf, replySize);
  if (result < 0) {
    std::cerr << "Error reading from routing socket. Error code: " << errno << std::endl;
    close(sockfd);
    return;
  }

  // Process the RTM_GET reply
  processRouteReply(destination, replyBuf, result);

  close(sockfd);
}

int main() {
  // Replace with the specific destination address
  const char* destination = "100.92.128.0";

  // Buffer to store RTM_GET reply
  char replyBuf[2048];

  // Get route information with RTM_GET
  getRouteInfo(destination, replyBuf, sizeof(replyBuf));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I modified my code so that it copies the sockaddr_in structures from the RTM_GET reply directly to the RTM_DELETE message, instead of translating the addresses back and forth to strings. This way it worked.
I still don't know why the posted code *didn't* work